# Can I view Google+ check-ins on Google Maps?

Tags: google-plus, google-maps

Is there a way of viewing my Google+ check-ins as pointers on a Google Maps?

---

**UPDATE:** Now that Google Latitude has been retired, [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/41584/4406) is no longer relevant. How can I view my Google+ check-ins without Latitude?

Comment: Well, there's your [Google Location History](http://google.com/locationhistory), but that's just what your phone is automatically reporting, not necessarily the places you've specifically checked in.

Comment: It doesn't look possible with the "new" Google Maps. However, if you're still using the "Classic" Maps, you can go to "My Places" and under the "More" menu you can get a list of the places you've checked in. That seems the best you can do at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still see your Google Location History at https://maps.google.com/locationhistory/ assuming you have location tracking enabled. (Does it show check-in locations? I don't use that feature. For those who miss Latitude, there's now Google+ location sharing.)

Also in the new Google Maps, "My custom maps" is in the menu below the search box (it was restored recently), and you can click the gear icon to get to the "My Places" menu command.

*However the word is that there's no longer a way to view check-ins on a map.*

[If you can export your check-ins as (latitude, longitude) coordinates, you can import them into Google Fusion Tables. Fusion Tables can readily plot locations on a map.]

Comment: Location History is different, it doesn't show check-ins.

Comment: OK, @Curt, I got an answer to your question, in short, "no."

Comment: Thanks Jerry, unfortunately my bounty ended by the time I saw this, but have marked as answer. It's a shame its not so easy to see these mapped out anymore, I found it quite a useful feature

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Now that Google Latitude has been retired, my answer is no longer relevant.

---

I've found the answer.

You can view Google+ check-ins on [Google Latitude](https://latitude.google.com/latitude/b/0?hl=en) if the "Check-ins" tab is selected:

[image]

https://latitude.google.com/latitude/b/0/checkins

Answer (score 1):

Open [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com) and click "My Places". That should show what you were looking for.

Comment: My places just shows maps that I have stored?